# How to reference existing image added earlier for header

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, wordprocessingml

How do I add an entry to an existing `relationshipid` for an image that is already added in another part?

For example : I have a Word document with a Header and Footer. I add an image, say A.gif, to the header using the code `headerPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType)` and then call `FeedData` on it with a stream.

Now I want the same image to be displayed in the footer too, but without adding a duplicate entry of the same image and instead, referencing the same image that was added earlier for the header.

How do I add an entry to the *footer.xml.rels* file to reference the same `relationShipId` that exists for header?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to: 1) add a new image part, and 2) return an id to the added image:

```html
ImagePart imagePart = addImagePart(partType, existingRelationShipId);
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(imageFilePath, FileMode.Open))
{
 imagePart.FeedData(stream);
}
headerPart= currentPart;
return headerPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart);
```

To add only a reference to an already existing image, use the id obtained earlier (above):

```html
var extPart = headerPart.GetPartById(existingRelationShipId);
footerPart.AddPart(extPart, existingRelationShipId);
```